# Non-compliant syntax and Natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have been having trouble with my BIB file (exported from Zotero) and have tracked the problem down to non-compliant syntax being used in the URL fileds of my BIB entries. So when attempting to compile using a bibliography style that includes the URL, such as "plainnat", I have been receiving the error message "Misplaced alignment tab character &". The problem is that many of the URLs I have in my URL fields contain "&". Is the only way around this problem to delete the URL entries?

I also have another question; when I attempt to use the "plain" style, the citations do not include the author, only "(author?)". Is this normal?

A simple example illustrating these issues is copied below.

TEX file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{\bf{WIP}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\citet{blah_general_2008}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyLibrary}

\end{document}
```

BIB file

```
@article{blah_general_2008,
    title = {On Blah},
    volume = {1},
    url = {https://www.blah&.com},
    urldate = {2013-09-15},
    journal = {Journal of Blah},
    author = {Blah, Z.},
    month = apr,
    year = {2008},
    pages = {1--2},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Regarding the first problem you describe: Do the problems go away if you load either the `url` or the `hyperref` package?

Comment: `plainnat ` fixes the issue but now I don't have my citations to be numbers e.g. `(1)`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To typeset the contents of fields containing URLs correctly, it's helpful to load a package such as `url` or `hyperref`.

The bibliography style `plain` is one of the original BibTeX style files. As it's more than twenty years old by now, it's maybe not surprising that it doesn't recognize fields such as `url`. If you want to display URLs -- and I would assume that you do -- use a newer style, such as `plainnat`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\citet{blah_general_2008}
\bibliography{MyLibrary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this fixes the issue but now I don't have my citations to be numbers e.g. `(1)`. How do I fix this?

Comment: @CharlieParker - To change the style of the citation call-outs from authoryear to numeric, you'll need to change `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}`.